# How to clear/delete contents of .txt file in matlab

Tags: matlab, file

How can I either delete the contents of a .txt file so that it becomes a blank file or it deletes the file altogether? I'm reading in from the .txt file and if I don't delete the contents from the previous time it ran, it will omit results that I want to account for.

Comment: Have you tried `fopen` with the `w` permission. This will "open or create a new file for writing. Discard existing contents, if any."

Comment: After searching a bit more, I did find that. Ended up going with fopen('WorkingMemory.txt','w') at the beginning of the file. Was just hoping there was a way that would be more elegant than opening it when I didn't need it yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose your file is named `to_be_deleted.txt`, you can simply use the following command to delete the file altogether:

```
delete 'to_be_deleted.txt';
```

On the other hand, if you simply want to clear it's contents, just open it using `fopen` with the write attribute as follows:

```
fopen('to_be_deleted.txt','w');
```

Comment: Note, if you are using a variable to store the filename, you must use parenthesis with delete. 
`delete(myFileName);`